# Commits and associated objects (within revision range) to remove from local repository

Tags: git

Developer's local repository is linked to remote. Developer works on feature branch. Feature branch was pushed to remote. Among other local branches that branch the feature branch shows shortest distance to merge-base to (no other merge bases in between) is also present on remote (upstream branch - is this the right word? I guess ProGit book uses this word in same sense). Feature branch is not yet merged to upstream branch.

As last handling developer deleted upstream branch from local repository. How to delete from local repository all commits yet those commits underlying objects of other types (associated trees, blobs) located on upstream branch but not present on feature branch, in git syntax revision range `^feature-br upstream-br` , or `feature-br..upstream-br` ?    Developer wants to do subsequently from-scratch pull of upstream branch, as possibly a failure is present on this distance of commits local repository (one of last pulls were conducted upstream branch while remote was in heavy defect).

UPDATE In meantime this was achieved (during upstream branch is deleted from local repository). Please see first two comments below for more details.

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (441350/441350), done.
dangling commit xx..
dangling blob xxx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling blob xx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling tree xx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling blob xx..
dangling blob xx..
dangling tree xx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling commit xx..
dangling blob xx..
```

However these are results for whole repository, its whole version history. It is unclear how big is fraction to be assigned to branch and revision range in mind here.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do, this reads a bit as if it was auto-translated. Are you trying to fix some corruption because you suspect some objects (trees, blobs, ...) have been corrupted locally? Or are you talking about `git gc`?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I am trying to fix some corruption because myself suspects some objects (trees, blobs, ...) have been corrupted locally.  Did me mention git gc in my Q? If yes, sorry for that, It was not my intention to refer in Q to git gc literally. Anyhow I considered to use it to try cleaning objects that revision range.

Comment: If you suspect the local repo to be "good", but the remote repo "bad"/corrupted, then why not clone the remote repo to a different path on your drive and see if it works?

Comment: If I suspect remote be corrupted why am I doing git gc with no ssh nor others, means locally?  "Developer wants to do subsequently from-scratch pull of upstream branch, as possibly a failure is present on this distance of commits local repository"  If remote is suspected be bad why is developer considering to pull the branch once again and from scratch?

Comment: "Dangling" commits and blobs are *normal*. No errors are shown in your output above. (I cannot make heads or tails of the remainder of the *question*, but it seems like the fsck output is alarming you: rest assured there's nothing wrong shown here.)

Comment: @Na13-c creating a new clone from the remote repository will tell you if the remote repo is corrupted or not. If the clone succeeds, everything is fine and nothing is corrupted. If the remote repo is corrupted, the clone will fail. If you have direct access to the remote repo (self-hosted server), run `git fsck` there (and not locally)